# Color at PDF only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, d3.js

I'm using D3.js and I convert the graphics to PDF, the problem is that when I see the PDF in Chrome it works perfect, but when I see it in Adobe PDF, for example, the color is always black.

It seems that only Chrome recognizes the attribute. I've tried to use another attribute but it doesn't work.

There is an image of what is happening.
The first is the image of the PDF in Chrome and the second is on Adobe.

[image: Graphic on PDF in Chrome]

[image: Graphic on PDF in Adobe]

Here you can download the pdf and open it with Chrome and Adobe to see the problem: http://docdro.id/vDluo16

Comment: Provide some code snippet, So I can have a look and help you out

Comment: Please also share a sample result pdf for analysis.

Comment: @mkl sorry for the delay, here is the pdf. You can download it and then try to open it with Chrome and Adobe, you'll see the problem. Thanks for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

*The following describes objects in the result PDF and why Chrome interprets it wrong.*

The pie chart segments are drawn by filling a path with a radial color shading.

E.g. in case of the biggest segment, the shading with the name **Sh2** is used. It is defined in the indirect PDF object 12 with references to objects 13 and 14:

```
12 0 obj
<<
/ShadingType 3
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Coords [0 0 0 0 0 0]
/Domain [0 1]
/Function 13 0 R
/Extend [true true]
>> 
13 0 obj
<<
/FunctionType 3
/Domain [0 1]
/Functions [14 0 R]
/Bounds []
/Encode [0 1]
>> 
14 0 obj
<<
/FunctionType 2
/Domain [0 1]
/C0 [1 0.6 0.2]
/C1 [0 0 0]
/N 1
>>
```

Consider the **Coords** array `[0 0 0 0 0 0]` (the shadings of the other pie chart segments have the same entry here). It is specified as

> **Coords** array *(Required)* An array of six numbers [*x*<sub>0</sub> *y*<sub>0</sub> *r*<sub>0</sub> *x*<sub>1</sub> *y*<sub>1</sub> *r*<sub>1</sub>] specifying the centres and radii of the starting and ending circles, expressed in the shading’s target coordinate space. The radii *r*<sub>0</sub> and *r*<sub>1</sub> shall both be greater than or equal to 0. If one radius is 0, the corresponding circle shall be treated as a point; if both are 0, nothing shall be painted.

In case of the shading at hand, therefore, **nothing shall be painted,** in particular not in the respective starting color (in the case above **C0** `[1 0.6 0.2]` of the function defined in object 14) of the shading of each segment.

Thus, Chrome's PDF renderer here is wrong.

Adobe Reader (which paints everything black) most likely also is wrong here but I'm not 100% sure that there is no justification for painting everything not covered by the radial shading in black.

Most likely, though, the preview of the sample document on www.docdroid.net is correct:

[image: preview screenshot]

---

The question remains why the combination of D3.js and conversion to PDF results in these unwanted color definitions. It might be an issue in the code calling the D3.js functionality or a bug in either D3.js or the converter used.